# Start SharePoint 2013 workflow from a SharePoint 2010 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

we have the following problem:

In our environment we have two lists:

```
PositionF
ArchivWFC
```

We have attached a SharePoint 2010 workflow to the list PositionF. This workflow creates an item in the list ArchivWFC.

In the list ArchivWFC we have created a SharePoint 2013 workflow. This workflow should start when the SharePoint 2010 workflow created the item in the list. (Workflow settings: manual start, item creation)

The problem is that the workflow doesn't start. I've tested the same with a SharePoint 2010 workflow in the list ArchivWFC. This workflow runs immediately, but we need to use a 2013 workflow because we are using the rest api.

The first workflow needs to be a 2010 workflow. A 2013 workflow in this list would cause a save conflict.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used an event receiver (ItemAdded) with the following code:

```
        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);

        //Updating the column
        properties.ListItem["EventReceiver"] = "True";

        //Commit change
        properties.ListItem.Update();
    }
```

The event receiver writes a "True" in the Column "EventReceiver". This update fires then the 2010 workflow.

Comment: Could you please more details on how you solved your questions (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).